# Fragment is blank in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

First off: I am aware there are a number of similar questions, however, none of the suggestions worked.

I have a ViewPager that I would like to use with fragments. The ViewPager works, and I can see in the log that I can scroll left and right. I can see the animation when I try to scroll left and there's no previous item (or right when there's no following item). However, the screen remains blank. The fragment itself is functional, however, I've tried it in a different context.

I am using the `androidx` namespaced packages.

Things I've tried (`<-->` means I've tried both):

- `FragmentPagerAdapter` <--> `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`
- `getFragmentManager()` <--> `getChildFragmentManager()`as the `FragmentManager` for the adapter
- `setSaveFromParentEnabled` to false.
- `setOffscreenPageLimit` to the number of fragments.

Relevant code (I have taken out sections of code that are irrelevant to this question):

The `Fragment` that contains the `ViewPager`:

```
public class AddListingMediaFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewPager viewPagerTop;
    private AddMediaAdapter addMediaAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_listing_media, container, false);
        setupViewPagerTop(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void setupViewPagerTop(View view) {
        viewPagerTop = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_top);
        addMediaAdapter = new AddMediaAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        viewPagerTop.setAdapter(addMediaAdapter);
        viewPagerTop.setSaveFromParentEnabled(false);
        viewPagerTop.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
    }
}
```

The `Adapter` (please do note, as mentioned, that I've tried both `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`:

```
public class AddMediaAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = AddMediaAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public AddMediaAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.i(TAG, "getItem: " + String.valueOf(position));
        return new AddListingMediaCameraFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
```

The layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_top"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        />

    <include
        layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_add_listing_media_gallery"
        />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to override `isViewFromObject` in your adapter, `FragmentPagerAdapter` has already taken care of it. `ViewPager` calls this method to decide how to render the pages.

Your `view == object` will return false because the object is always a `Fragment` not a `View`. So just drop the override, and it will fix the issue.